# Odoo: selecting a treeview-item should link to special view

Tags: odoo

in a custom module we have different detail-View-definitions and also 2 different tree views

how can i achieve that if i use the second tree-view, selecting an item within this tree-view should target to the second detail-view.

Sample Code:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="dummy_form_view">
        <field name="name">dummy.form</field>
        <field name="model">x_dummy.dummy</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="13"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="dummy" create="false" edit="false" delete="false">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"  nolabel="1"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="dummy_form_view2">
        <field name="name">dummy.form</field>
        <field name="model">x_dummy.dummy</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="15"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="dummy" delete="false" duplicate="false">
                <group>
                    <field name="name2"  />
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="dummy_tree_view">
        <field name="name">dummy.tree</field>
        <field name="model">x_dummy.dummy</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="name" context="{'form_view_ref': 'x_dummy.dummy_form_view2'}"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

So code below didn't work.

```
<field name="name" context="{'form_view_ref': 'your_module.your_view_id'}"/>
```

Then you can do it by linking the action with specific form view.

example of action

```
<record id="dummy_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
     <field name="name">Dummy</field>
     <field name="res_model">x_dummy.dummy</field>
     <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
     <field name="domain">[]</field>
     <field name="context">{}</field>
     <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create"></p>
     </field>
</record>
```

By default this action will link to **dummy_form_view** and **dummy_tree_view**

Here is an example of linking **dummy_form_view2** to **dummy_action**

```
  <record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="act_x_dummy_tree_view">
      <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
      <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
      <field name="view_id" ref="dummy_tree_view"/>
      <field name="act_window_id" ref="dummy_action"/>
  </record>

  <record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="act_x_dummy_form_view">
      <field eval="10" name="sequence"/>
      <field name="view_mode">form</field>
      <field name="view_id" ref="dummy_form_view2"/>
      <field name="act_window_id" ref="dummy_action"/>
  </record>
```

Remember that the sequence is important.

Comment: i added some sample code. Adding context= to the field in the tree view did not help. it still opens the first form-view